# What is the significance of this js code in apple “The 50 Billion Apps Countdown Promotion”?

Tags: javascript

this is the promotion page:
http://www.apple.com/itunes/50-billion-app-countdown/

and it link a js:
http://www.apple.com.cn/v/itunes/50-billion-app-countdown/a/scripts/counter.js

```
    AC.onDOMReady(function() {
var e = "j", t = new Counter({
    container: AC.Element.selectAll(".counter")[0],
    dataURL: "/itunes/store/counters/il6ark7ec." + e + "s",
    staticImagePath: "http://images.apple.com/itunes/shared/counter/images/counter_noscript.png",
    targetCount: 50000000000,
    stopAtTargetCount: true
});
```

});

so Splice the string

`var e="j"`

`"/itunes/store/counters/il6ark7ec." + e + "s"`

to

`http://www.apple.com.cn/itunes/store/counters/il6ark7ec.js`

is it useful? or just only for fun..?

Comment: Interesting but I don't see the point... Seems like it's obfuscated, `!0`? That's what minifiers do...

Comment: @elclanrs  '!0=ture ', i make the format for this code so it change.. already fix..

Answer (score 2):

It's probably to make it harder for someone looking to scrape the file and all files linked within. A naive approach would be to look through the html source and download any other files referenced within that end with `css` or `js` (probably using a regular expression). This string concat would cause that to fail on this particular file.

Comment: And I think that includes search engine crawlers too :)